How to avoid reallocating an array of pointers when we dont know the exact size from start
Im trying to design a binary tree like data-struct except there is no limit on children each node can have. Now within each node I can declare node struct as such:
struct node {
  int id;
  int num_children;
  struct node ** child;
};

My question is is there a way to avoid using:

realloc in this scenario so to not end up with alot of fragmentation in memory when you free and reallocate? everytime I add a new child will need to go though this process
statically allocate finite amount of pointers in the array which means (a) at a certain point I will not be able to add to it & (b) some nodes will not have children so its a waste


Make a linked list of children. Sure it will have an overhead in both memory and time.

I suggest not worrying about it unless it actually becomes a performance bottleneck. realloc() often doesn't have to relocate because the initial allocation is rounded up to allow for growth.

Sounds like you're asking for a way to predict the future? AFAIK no one has ever figured out how to do that. Something has to give, you'll need to make your best guess on memory management. My two cents, over-allocating would be my least concern. Memory is cheap and very abundant these days (unless you're on a resource-constrained embedded system), if you allocated a few more MBs than you need, who cares? Here's one strategy for realloc

A singly- or doubly-linked list for the children will avoid the need for realloc.

Perl reallocs ever larger block. Something like max( needed_size + 4, needed_size * 1.2 ), I think.

Start by allocating a fixed number of child pointers, and add a member to store the current capacity of the list.  When you go to add a child to the list, if the list is a capacity, double the size.  This minimized the amount of realocations you need to do.
So a node is modified to look like this:
struct node {
  int id;
  int capacity;
  int num_children;
  struct node ** child;
};

To create a node:
struct node *newnode = malloc(sizeof *newnode);
newnode->num_children = 0;
newnode->capacity = 10;
newnode->child = malloc(sizeof *newnode->child * newnode->capacity);

To add a child when at capacity:
if (current->capacity == current->num_children) {
    current->capacity *= 2;
    current->child = realloc(current->child, 
         sizeof *current->child * newnode->capacity);
}
current->child[current->num_children++] = new_child;

Note: error checking omitted for brevity.

Thank you @dbush. in terms of runtime performance and memory usage would this approach be better than using double linked lists like-approach?

Runtime - for sure. Memory - depends. This approach will always have some "wasted" memory, while linked list is using only what it needs. It's just that it needs more.

@JJAdams There will be a small overhead in memory usage, depending on the starting capacity and how many nodes you eventually add.  As for performance, you shouldn't have to increase the capacity more than 10 to 20 times due to the doubling so that should minimize that portion.  An array will allow for more direct access rather than having to walk though a list.

@JJ Adams Re "would this approach be better than using double linked lists like-approach?", Depends on how you access the data. If you just access the head and/or tail, a linked list works great. But it's very expensive to access elements by position. Linked lists also have a lot of memory overhead (because of all the pointers and the large number of memory blocks). Where link lists shine is when it comes to inserting into and deleting from the start or middle. (Except it can be efficient to delete from a start of an array by having an offset count. Good for making a queue.)

struct node newnode = malloc Typo here. Also I'm not sure what the pointer-to-pointer is good for.
